# Tableview is not visible on UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

`UITableView` is not visible on the UIViewController Class.

On `Storyboard` added a new `UIViewController` set to related SlideViewcontroller class to it,  Add a new `UITableView` (tbl_Slide), set the datasource and delegate to UIViewController in storyboard for the added UITableView.
And also included the related datasource and delegate methods to the UIViewController class.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tbl_SlideMenu = [[UITableView alloc]
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.frame.size.width,    self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tbl_SlideMenu.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.tbl_SlideMenu.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.tbl_SlideMenu.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.tbl_SlideMenu.dataSource=self;
    self.tbl_SlideMenu.delegate=self; 
  [self.view addSubview:self.tbl_SlideMenu];
}
```

Since added the UITableView to the UIViewController for UIView, need not to induced above two lines of code

```
    self.tbl_SlideMenu = [[UITableView alloc]
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
  [self.view addSubview:self.tbl_SlideMenu];
```

Once I included the allocation and added to subview its showing the data with tableview.
Once I removed allocation and frame added to subview is not visible.

So what is need of storyboard where I added UITableView to   UIViewController for UIView (view default.)  once Component added to storyboard and framed need not to allocate and frame in code.

Advance Thanks
Hope for best posible answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u added the tableview in storyboard there is no need to initialise the view components in the code in this case u don't need below lines as u mentioned

```
self.tbl_SlideMenu = [[UITableView alloc]
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

however u need to create a `outlet` for your `tableview` to access the tableview in `code` that means as soon as view is loaded all your view components are initialised in your case tableview is initialised and u can ready to use it and also u don't need below lines of code if u set datasource and delegate in storyboard

```
self.tbl_SlideMenu.dataSource=self;
self.tbl_SlideMenu.delegate=self;
```

since u configured your tableview datasource and delegate and also added tableview to view controller's view there is no need of below line also

```
[self.view addSubview:self.tbl_SlideMenu];
```

and second way is as u mentioned creating the view in pure code, in this case u have to do all things by your self from initialising to adding the view component to controller's view as u mentioned like below

```
self.tbl_SlideMenu = [[UITableView alloc]
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.frame.size.width,    self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain]; //creating the tableview
self.tbl_SlideMenu.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.tbl_SlideMenu.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; //configuring the view
self.tbl_SlideMenu.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
self.tbl_SlideMenu.dataSource=self; //setting the datasource and delegate
self.tbl_SlideMenu.delegate=self;  
[self.view addSubview:self.tbl_SlideMenu]; //adding it to tableview
```

hope u get this

**Edit**

it is working fine for me, i crossed checked it with some dummy values, for example as i mentioned , dragged and dropped a tableview, set its datasource and delegate to `View Controller` in storyboard and connected a outlet in `ViewController.h` file, like below,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tbl_SlideMenu;

@end
```

and in `ViewController.m` file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  self.tbl_SlideMenu.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
  self.tbl_SlideMenu.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
    return cell;
 }

 @end
```

and i got output showing the tableview with 5 "Hello" on each row

Comment: @Thanks for replay the problem is tableview is not visible, I removed the datasource and delegate self.tbl_SlideMenu.dataSource=self; //setting the datasource and delegate
self.tbl_SlideMenu.delegate=self;   and allocation and frame line of code and also adding to subview line of code from my code in viewdidload in storyboard drag and drop uitableview to uiviewcontroller and set the delegate and datasource and set tbl_SlideMenu. when run the application in simulator X-Code 7.1 SDK 9.1 tableview is not visible at all!

Comment: check  auto layout is enabled  in storyboard, if enabled then disable it

Comment: i check auto layout which is enabled, after disabled also issue is same

Comment: have u created the outlet for your tableview .. ? it is working fine for me .. i will edit the answer

Comment: i really don't understand what is happening, but for testing do like above